# 10 W LED COB on 12 V

Tags: led, resistors, 12v, watts

So say I have a 10 W LED, most have a forward voltage of 9-11 V and a maximum current of 700 mA.

If I wanted to connect it up to 13 V (a fully charged SLA battery) couldn't I simply do 11-13=2 (LED drops 11 V and rest is across resistor)then 2/0.7 = 2.85, meaning I would need a 2.8 ohm resistor?

And 2 * 0.7 = 1.4, so that means I would need to use a 1.5 W resistor (or greater).

Is this all correct? I know it wouldn't be the most efficient but I'm checking to see if I'm understanding this correctly.

A more efficient way would be using a current regulated/limited supply, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. It may be more convenient to build it out of 0.5Ohm 0.5W resistors - multiple resistors in series will spread the load. Another reason to do this is that you can measure the actual current and insert another 0.5R to bring it down. Don't forget to heatsink the LED.